# In the Google Play Console, there is a report of Crashes and ANRs that contain an error related to "androidx.fragment.app.q."

Tags: android, crash, fragment, production-environment

I recently migrated my Android app to Kotlin, and after the migration, I started encountering a persistent error in Google Play Console Crashes and ANRs. The error message indicates "androidx.fragment.app.q" as the source of the issue. Unfortunately, I'm unable to identify the root cause of this error and how to fix it.

I have attached a screenshot of the error from the Google Play Console for reference.

Could someone please help me understand the cause of this error and provide guidance on how to resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

[Google Play store Crashes and ANRs report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8zlT.png)

verified the gradle dependencies all looks good.

```
 implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'

    // Other dependencies...
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    implementation 'com.nex3z:flow-layout:1.3.1'

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.2.0'

    implementation 'com.jaredrummler:colorpicker:1.1.0'
```